# Determing whether a $_POST["X"] is null

Tags: php, mysql

How would I determine if a $_POST is null? I want to do an if/else based on whether an ID is submitted or not, to determine whether a record should be inserted into a MySQL database, or updated.

Would I use `isset($_POST["ID"])` ?

Comment: Yes, use `isset($_POST['key'])`.  You could also use `array_key_exists('key', $_POST)`, but `isset()` is simple and easy to read.

Comment: @Michael I thought `isset()` was used to check if `$_POST['ID']` existed, not if it had a value or not?

Comment: @Rawb92 true, you should never use isset() for $_POST values.

Comment: Note that `isset($_POST['key'])` will give a different result from `array_key_exists('key', $_POST)` if, for some reason, the value is `null`. `isset` will return `false` if the key exists but it's `null`, while `array_key_exists` will return `true`.

Comment: What should be used for $_POST values then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several functions in php for this.

People use [empty](http://php.net/empty) or [isset](http://php.net/isset) for this purpose. Many use the one and dont think about the difference.

This example from the documentation shows clearly the difference.

```
$var = 0;

// Evaluates to true because $var is empty
if (empty($var)) {
    echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
}

// Evaluates as true because $var is set
if (isset($var)) {
    echo '$var is set even though it is empty';
}
```

In this particular case, you should use **empty** and not isset, because the variable can be set, but empty.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use empty():

```
if (!empty($_POST["ID"])) {
  //rest of code here
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `empty` here as it will give false negatives for values such as `"0"`. Use `isset` instead.